# Why builder design pattern is used to create Spark Session?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, design-patterns

I am new to Spark. 
Can anyone help me to understand why SparkSession creation follows builder design pattern when Scala has other recommended design pattern (with a case class) to handle same situation?

Answer (score 0):

From a user perspective it is good to use the builder pattern. SparkSession can have many arguments upon instantiation and builder pattern is just a clean way to handle them.